# using NSOpenPanel to get folder location remove file://localhost

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsopenpanel

I'm using NSOpenPanel to set a folder on my application but I'm getting this as the path for the folder "file://localhost/Users/juan/"

This is my code:

```
    NSOpenPanel * setDirectory = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    setDirectory.canChooseFiles=NO;
    setDirectory.canCreateDirectories=YES;
    setDirectory.canChooseDirectories=YES;
    setDirectory.directoryURL=_path;
    [setDirectory beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
        NSLog(@" results %ld", result);
        if (NSFileHandlingPanelCancelButton){
            NSLog(@"cancel");

        }
        if (NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {

            self.path = [[setDirectory URLs] objectAtIndex:0];

        }

    }];
}
```

My question is how or what I need to do to get the absolute path such as "/Users/juan/Desktop/" without file://localhost.

I really appreciate any pointers.

Comment: If it makes sense at all for the user to choose multiple items, why are you only handling a random item from the user's choices? If it doesn't make sense, why aren't you turning off `allowsMultipleSelection`?

Answer (score 4):

To do this, call the `path` method of the `NSURL` object.

Comment: Although you really should just use the URL nowadays. The number of things for which you still must use a path is small and declining.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem I was using `[bitmapData writeToFile:nameandPath atomically:YES];` and It was giving me a error.
 I switch to `[bitmapData writeToURL:nameandPath atomically:YES];` and everything is working perfectly.

Comment: The difference being that `writeToFile::` takes a path as an NSString object, whereas `writeToURL::` takes a URL as an NSURL object. URLs are the preferred way to refer to files now. By the way, both of those methods are deprecated; you should instead use `writeToURL:options:error:`, and handle the error if it fails.